# Вывести в консоль имена и значения всех полей экземпляра класа

Tags: c#, рефлексия

Я пытаюсь сделать это так, но у меня не выходит.

```
string data = "";
foreach (var prop in экземплярКласса.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    data += String.Format("{0}={1}{2}", prop.Name, prop.GetValue(экземплярКласса, null), Environment.NewLine);
}
Console.WriteLine(data);
```

Comment: по умолчанию выводятся только публичные свойства. Для точной настройки смотри [Type.GetProperties - метод (BindingFlags)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/kyaxdd3x(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Если вам нужно выводить поля, то надо использовать метод `GetFields()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
MyClass myInstance = new MyClass();    
FieldInfo[] fields = myInstance.GetType().GetFields();
// или 
FieldInfo[] fields = myInstance.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | 
                                          BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                                          BindingFlags.Instance);

 for(int i = 0; i < fields .Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The value of {0} is: {1}",
                myFields[i].Name, fields [i].GetValue(myInstance));
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Если вы используете .NET 4.5 и выше, удобнее воспользоваться новым Reflection API, представленным классом [TypeInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.typeinfo(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
IEnumerable<FieldInfo> fields = yourInstance.GetType().GetTypeInfo().DeclaredFields;

foreach (var field in fields.Where(x => !x.IsStatic)) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", field.Name, field.GetValue(yourInstance));
}
```